# Authenticating Laravel's API with Sanctum and Firebase Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Laravel to create an API.
I am also using Firebase Authentication for user authentication.

I would like to treat the "idToken" issued by Firebase Authentication as a Bearer Token.
And I would like to confirm this with Sanctum.

Since `idToken` is used for Bearer Token, no database is used.
However, there are only samples that allow the users table to have a token.

I simply want to verify the Bearer token using Firebase Authentication's verifyIdToken method to verify the token.
How can I use Sanctum to handle this kind of case?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me about it.

P.S.
My native language is not English, so I apologize for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit too late to answer but I am leaving an answer for somebody who might stumble upon this, I faced this same situation and here is my workaround for this:

### Step 1. Configure Firebase SDK:

Ensure you have the Firebase Admin SDK installed in your Laravel project. You can install it via Composer:

```
composer require kreait/firebase-php
```

### Step 2. Create a Middleware for Firebase Authentication:

Create a new middleware named: FirebaseAuthMiddleware (or whatever you would like to call it)

```
php artisan make:middleware FirebaseAuthMiddleware
```

### Step 3. Write Middleware

This middleware will use `verifyIdToken` method provided by the SDK installed earlier

```
// app/Http/Middleware/FirebaseAuthMiddleware.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FirebaseAuthMiddleware
{
    protected $firebaseAuth;

    public function __construct(Auth $firebaseAuth)
    {
        $this->firebaseAuth = $firebaseAuth;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        try {
            $verifiedToken = $this->firebaseAuth->verifyIdToken($token);
            $request->attributes->add(['firebase_user' => $verifiedToken->getClaim('sub')]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### Step 4. Register the Middleware:

You will need to register this middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'firebase.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\FirebaseAuthMiddleware::class,
];
```

### Step 5: Use the new Middleware:

This is it for firebase part, now you can simply use this middleware on your routes as you would use sanctum:

```
Route::middleware(['firebase.auth', 'auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    // Your authenticated routes here
});
```

The above implementation is completely dependant on your route, you could use either or both depending on your usecase.

### Next Steps:

Since you are not using any traditional database for tokens, there is a need for sanctum to identify the users, for that purpose we can create a token repository for sanctum to function properly, here is the overview how will it work:

**Create a custom token respository using Sanctum's Token Repository Contract:** `Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\TokenRepository`

**Bind your custom token repository in the** `AppServiceProvider`

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

use App\CustomTokenRepository;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\TokenRepository::class,
        \App\FirebaseTokenRepository::class
    );
}
```

## Implementation of above mentioned steps:

Keep following if you didn't understand how the above needs to be implemented.

### Step 5.1: Create a Custom Token Repository

First of all you will need to create a custom token repository: `app/FirebaseTokenRepository.php`

```
// app/CustomTokenRepository.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\TokenRepository as TokenRepositoryContract;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class FirebaseTokenRepository implements TokenRepositoryContract
{
    public function create($userId, $name, $token, $abilities)
    {
        return SanctumPersonalAccessToken::create([
            'id' => $token->id,
            'tokenable_id' => $userId,
            'tokenable_type' => SanctumPersonalAccessToken::getUserModel(),
            'name' => $name,
            'token' => $token->plainTextToken,
            'abilities' => $abilities,
        ]);
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return SanctumPersonalAccessToken::find($id);
    }

    public function findToken($token)
    {
        return SanctumPersonalAccessToken::where('token', hash('sha256', $token))->first();
    }

    public function update($token, $abilities)
    {
        // Update token abilities if needed
        $token->update(['abilities' => $abilities]);

        return $token;
    }

    public function delete($token)
    {
        $token->delete();
    }

    // You can implement additional methods as needed for your use case
}
```

That's it the token repository is created now we need to make our serice provider aware about using this and make some modifications to Sanctum's behavior.

### Step 5.2: Bind Custom Token Repository:

Update your `AppServiceProvider.php` like this:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

use App\FirebaseTokenRepository;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\TokenRepository as TokenRepositoryContract;

public function register()
{
    //...

    $this->app->singleton(TokenRepositoryContract::class, FirebaseTokenRepository::class);
}
```

This tells Laravel to use the newly created custom (firebase) token repository whenever it needs to interact with the TokenRepository contract.

### Step 5.3: Update Configuration (If you are using SPAs):

Now we need to prevent Sanctum from using Laravel's session for authentication. for that purpose make sure you are not using `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware in api middleware, and also in `sanctum.php` config file update `stateful` key from:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS')),
```

to:

```
'stateful' => [''],
```

and with this step, we are done, now the application is ready to be used with Firebase Authentication and Sanctum. This solution might differ slightly based on laravel Versions, any kind of Edits are always welcome.

*This was implemented on `Laravel 10` with `PHP 8.1` tested on **Blade Templates**, **React Native** and **NextJs**. Sincere apologies for any kind of syntax errors.